# hadoop installation, to start secondary namenode, nodemanagers, and resource managers

Tags: linux, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, namenode

I have installed hadoop 3.1.0 clusters on 4 linux machines, hadoop1(master),hadoop2,hadoop3,and hadoop4.

I ran `start-dfs.sh` and `start-yarn.sh`, and saw only namenodes and datanodes running with `jps`. secondary namenodes, nodemanagers and resourcemanagers failed. I tried a few solutions and this is where I got. How to configure and start secondary namenodes, nodemanagers and resroucemanagers?

About secondary namenodes logs says

```
java.net.BindException: Port in use: hadoop1:9000
...
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
...
```

About node manager and resource manager log says

```
2021-02-21 03:29:03,463 WARN org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@51d719bc{/,file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8042-node-_-any-8548809575065892553.dir/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}{/node}
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataSource
  at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.webapp.JAXBContextResolver.<init>(JAXBContextResolver.java:52)
  at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.webapp.WebServer$NMWebApp.setup(WebServer.java:153)
  while locating org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.webapp.JAXBContextResolver
```

I have hdfs-site.xml

```
    <property>
            <name>dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address</name>
            <value>hadoop1:9000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
            <value>file:/app/hadoop/hadoop-3.1.0/name</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
            <value>file:/app/hadoop/hadoop-3.1.0/data</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>dfs.replication</name>
            <value>3</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
            <value>true</value>
    </property>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
    <property>
            <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
            <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
            <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
            <value>hadoop1:8032</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
            <value>hadoop1:8030</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
            <value>hadoop1:8031</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
            <value>hadoop1:8033</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
            <value>hadoop1:8088</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
            <value>1024</value>
    </property>
    <property>
            <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores</name>
            <value>1</value>
    </property>
```

workers

```
hadoop1
hadoop2 
hadoop3   
hadoop4
```

etc/hosts

```
192.168.0.111 hadoop1
192.168.0.112 hadoop2
192.168.0.113 hadoop3
192.168.0.114 hadoop4

127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

Comment: Did you check logs for any error?

Comment: About nodesmanagers and resource managers. I see 'google' in the error message. Does it mean that the server needs to be in contact with google service? I am in China and google is blocked here

Comment: Seems issue is with your classpath. See the error you pasted. Do you have appropriate jars in place?

Comment: my classpath appears so when starting the name nodes, data nodes...:classpath = /app/hadoop/hadoop-3.1.0/etc/hadoop:/app/hadoop/hadoop-3.1.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpcore-4.4.4.jar:/app/hadoop/hadoop-3.1.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-util-9.3.19.v20170502....it should be alright otherwise namenodes and datanodes wouldnt have started

Comment: my secondary name manager runs now. I had fs.defaultFS hadoop1:9000 as well, creating a conflict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had jdk15.0.2 installed and it had some sort of problem with hadoop 3.1.0. Later I installed jdk8 and changed java_home. It went all fine!

About secondary node manager, I had hadoop1:9000 for both fs.defaultFS and dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address, and therefore created a conflict. I changed secondary into 9001 and it went all fine!